# I can't access 'title' on mongosh - getting undefine

Tags: node.js, mongo-shell

```
//here is my schema
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ResortSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    descriptor: String,
    places: String,
    location: String
});
var Resortdata = mongoose.model('holidayresorts', ResortSchema);
module.exports = Resortdata;

// index.js - where I tried to access 'places' and 'descriptors'
const sample = array => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.lenght)];
const seedDB = async () => {
    await holidayresorts.deleteMany({});
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        const random5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        const Resort = new holidayresorts ({
            location: `${cities[random5].city} , ${cities[random5].state}`,
            title: `${sample(descriptor)} ${sample(places)}`
        })
        await Resort.save();
    }
}
seedDB();

// what I am getting in on mongosh
  {
    _id: ObjectId("630cecf45a6457bfe74c0b9d"),
    title: 'undefined undefined',
    location: 'Owerri , Imo',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Please I need help, why am I getting 'undefined' for my title?
I think my Schema is correct
I can't really figure out what is wrong
I am thinking it is from my array

Please I need help

Have been stuck for days now

Help me

Comment: // my array module.exports.descriptor = [
    'Bridge',
    'Flyover',
    'Underground',
    'Fountain',
    'Hotels'
]

module.exports.places = [
    'Rockvilla',
    'Hillyside',
    'Hotelzones',
    'Parks',
    "Cozy"
]

Comment: You misspelled `length` on `array.lenght`.